# triggers inside cruisecontrol.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Basically I have a project A inside my cruisecontrol that has 2 different triggers. One is an intervalTrigger which checks to see if modification exists in the repository and the builds the project A. And the other one is a projectTrigger which makes the project A gets build if project B is built. Now I have a executable file and I only want this to deppen on my intervalTrigger and not on the projectTrigger. Is that possible???? How????

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but you can always create a new project C and set just the interval trigger to execute your file.

Comment: A single project can't conditionally perform actions based on which trigger was pulled.  You need to set up several projects.